# Auto cc when recipient replies to php-script sent email

Tags: php, html, email

I have a standard php 'send mail from html form' script. Is there any way to modify this such that the recipient would then automatically cc an address into their reply?

Hope that's clear, and thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean automatically add a Cc: when someone replies to your emails? Obviously that's not possible.

Comment: copy->paste Your "standard php 'send mail from html form' script.". We don't have magic crystal ball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the best you could do is include a cc in your headers to that address.  Then if your lucky the user will select "reply all".